# data is not inserted into oracle database from python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g

Hi i'm a newbie to coding.i have written a code for registration form and the code run without an error.

```
def clicked():
      try:

            con = cx_Oracle.connect('app/reshmaa@10.23.129.216/XE')
            cur = con.cursor()
            emp_id=txt.get()      
            first_name=txt1.get()
            last_name=txt2.get()
            email_id=txt3.get()
            """if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$",email_id,re.IGNORECASE):
               email_id=txt3.get()"""     

            mobile_no=int(txt4.get())   
            last_update=str(date.today())


            statement="insert into registration(emp_id, first_name, last_name, email_id, mobile_no, last_update, pass_word) values('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s',to_date('%s','dd/mm/yyyy'),'%s')"%
            (emp_id, first_name,last_name,email_id,mobile_no, last_update, pass_word) 
            cur.execute(statement)
            con.commit()
            max_char= 8
            allchar= string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%&*'
            random.seed=(os.urandom(16))
            pass_word= "".join(random.choice(allchar) for x in range(max_char))
            messagebox.showinfo("Success","Your password is "+ pass_word)


      except:
            messagebox.showerror("Error","Check Your Details")

btn = Button(window, text="Register", bg="dodgerblue4", fg="silver", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=5, row=7)
```

When i click register button it shows the error message box in except statement and stops. It does not show any error in the python shell(version 3.6.2) and the data entered is not inserted into my oracle database table.
can someone help me with what error has been made in my code?

Comment: Can you post the actual exception message? as in:
    ' exception as e: print e'

Comment: you mean like make the try,except keywords as comments in the above code and post the error thrown by python shell?

Comment: So right now, your except clause is 'messagebox.showerror("Error","Check Your Details")'. This will not show the error caused, only the predefined message.